# hacer un subquery con un where dentro, laravel

Tags: laravel

tenía un query en el cual podía hacer todo en la misma consulta, el query era

```
return Place::doesntHave('locationGroupPlace')->has('site')->limit($limit)->get();
```

pero ahora necesito reemplazar esto, ya que necesito hacer otra consulta, la relación 'site', tiene una columna llamada `'state'`.

necesito hacer exactamente la misma consulta, pero esta vez "donde un site tenga la columna state con valor 1"

he intentado haciendo esto

```
    $place = Place::doesntHave('locationGroupPlace')->with(['site' => function ($query) use ($limit) {
        $query->where('state', '=', 1)->take($limit)->get();
     }]);
    return $place;
```

pero no obtengo ningún resultado, así que me está saliendo mal.

Cómo puedo resolverlo?

Comment: Aquí: *`.......................take($limit)->get();`*, no necesitas emplear un get al final, si no al final de la consulta principal, por otro lado ¿puedes explicar mejor por favor que resultado obtienes con la consulta actual?

Comment: Recomiendo leas la documentación en esta sección: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prueba de esta manera

```php
 $place = Place::doesntHave('locationGroupPlace')->has('site')->with(['site' => function 
 ($query) {
        $query->where('state', '=', 1);
 }])
 ->take($limit)
 ->get();
 
 return $place;
```

No es necesario que apliques el `get();` ya que *Laravel* solo esta adicionando la `Closure` a la consulta, debes de colocarlo es fuera de ella

Comment: gracias! sin embargo, he enviado una recomendación de edición, le había quitado el "has" a la consulta pensando que había que quitarlo ahora que hago la consulta, pero no era así

Comment: @AndréCuellarAvaroma ahmm perfecto entiendo, ya esta aprobada la edición

Comment: Tener cuidado porque con esta consulta se pueden traer Places que no tengan sites con state = 1. Para forzar a que el place si o si tenga un site con state = 1 hay que utilizar whereHas()

Comment: @LeonardoCabré muchas gracias por el dato..!!

Comment: @LeonardoCabré gracias!, al whereHas te refieres a ponerlo en lugar del ->has('site')?

Comment: @AndréCuellarAvaroma exacto.